# I am downloading pdf's to internal storage but my pdf viewer can not find them

Tags: android, file, directory-structure

I download a pdf file to internal storage and then programmatically create buttons that take them to an action view. I can listFiles[] and Toast that they are there but the pdf viewer says file does not exist or file can not be viewed.

These are the main components of the write to internal storage during download.

```
private File file;
file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), filename+".pdf");
// Output stream to write file in internal storage
                    OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
```

Then in another activity I get the filenames from the database and create a table with buttons

```
// ....Inside a for loop ..... 
Button c3 = new Button(this);
        c3.setText("view");
        c3.setId(p.getPosterID());
        c3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                File pdfFile = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(filename+".pdf");
                if (pdfFile.exists()){
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
 //================================================================================
                    Log.d("path: ", path.toString());
    //this will log: file:///data/data/com.myapp.posterviewer/files/5453b54b83b5f.pdf
 //================================================================================
                    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    try{
                        startActivity(pdfIntent);
                    }
                    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                        Toast.makeText(ListPosters.this, "No Application Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(ListPosters.this, "The file does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Am I generating the path right with Uri path?
I am not able to see the files from windows explorer when in the app folder either.
But all my checks say file is exists and I thought that would be in the app root folder.

Comment: I suspect it might be a permission problem. I am not sure if the pdf viewer is allowed to read from your app's internal folder. Perhaps try and download to the external Downloads folder, which is also used if you download something from a browser.

Comment: Or, serve the file from your internal storage using `FileProvider`.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. I was just reading about using a pdf viewing library and someone mentioned you in a post from 2012. So, what pdf viewing library would you recommend 2 years later? I am just starting in java/android so FileProvider is new for me, Ill check it out.

Comment: "what pdf viewing library would you recommend 2 years later?" -- I would recommend opening the PDF in the user's desired PDF viewer, rather than using a library.

Comment: @CommonsWare Fair enough. However this is a kiosk type app. It will not be the users device.

Comment: In that case, a library may be more appropriate, but since I have never used a PDF rendering library, I cannot make any recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal Storage Only Visible to your Application. The OutSide Application(Pdf Viewer) Cannot Access it. Save you Pdf file in External Storage and then open it via Pdf Viewer

Comment: ok, i will try that now. Just as a side note, The first round of code saved the files to apps DOWNLOAD folder. Does that have special permission because I was able to view those by     public void `showDownload(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
        startActivity(i);
    }`?

Comment: You Can View it With in your Application. While Try to opening using the other application is the problem. Because one Application Cannot See the internal storage of the other application.Internet Permission is enough to use DownloadManager. but to save and read from external storage u need Write and read external storage permission